# Sql .Print maker producing all the products

Tags: sql

I have a table called "Product".There are three columns in that table.Maker,Model and Type.
Model is the primary that is used to link with other tables.The content in the table is like this

```
MODEL   MAKER   TYPE
1   A   Laptop
2   A   PC
3   B   Laptop
4   C   Laptop
5   B   Printer
6   D   Printer
7   B   PC
8   D   Printer
9   C   PC
10  A   Printer
```

I want only those makers who make all the three products.How to obtain the result?Please help Me.

Comment: format your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(MAKER) FROM Product 
WHERE MAKER IN (SELECT MAKER FROM Product WHERE TYPE='Laptop')
  AND MAKER IN (SELECT MAKER FROM Product WHERE TYPE='PC')
  AND MAKER IN (SELECT MAKER FROM Product WHERE TYPE='Printer');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try following query:**

```
select distinct(Maker) from product where Type="Printer" And Type="PC" And Type="Laptop"
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: No its not working.It is showing the maker who is producing only pc or laptop or both the product.Anyway thanks for the reply.